# Run Power.t.test for a data frame

Tags: r, sample

I'm trying to run `power.t.test` on a dataframe and trying to return samplesize(n) for each employee,but it's giving me this error.

> Error in power.t.test(delta = d.f$Delta, sd = d.f$sd, sig.level = 0.05,  : 
>     exactly one of 'n', 'delta', 'sd', 'power', and 'sig.level' must be NULL

This is what I've done so far.

```
dput(d.f)
structure(list(power = c(0.95, 0.95, 0.95, 0.95), sig.level = c(0.05, 
0.05, 0.05, 0.05), sd = c(4.93255160738102, 20.3907509926899, 
23.1325373816684, 6.0463892968789), delta = c(97, 97, 90, 96), 
    workedby = structure(1:4, .Label = c("emp1", "emp2", "emp3", 
    "emp4"), class = "factor"), newcolumn = c(0, 0, 0, 0)), .Names = c("power", 
"sig.level", "sd", "delta", "workedby", "newcolumn"), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = "data.frame")
```

first approach

```
 d.f$newcolumn <- 0

for (i in 1:nrow(d.f)) {
  n <- power.t.test(delta = d.f$delta, sd = d.f$sd, sig.level=.05, power = .8, type = "one.sample")
  d.f$newcolumn[i] <- n
}
head(d.f)
```

second approach:

```
apply(d.f[,c('power','sig.level','sd','delta')], 1, function(x) power.t.test(x) )
```

Can somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong. Basically, I want SampleSize returned for each employees.

Answer (score 1):

It takes a single value as input, not a data frame. The following works:

```
power.t.test(delta=d.f$delta[1], sig.level=d.f$sig.level[1], power=d.f$power[1], sd=d.f$sd[1])
```

You will need to wrap this in a loop and re-assign to the correct row in your "new column".

Comment: Thanks! that helped. When I run this it gives error...power.t.test(#n=10,
             power=.95, 
             sig.level=.05, 
             sd= 0.81,
             delta =91, 
             alternative = "two.sided"
            )  
Error in uniroot(function(n) eval(p.body) - power, c(2, 1e+07), tol = tol,  : 
  did not succeed extending the interval endpoints for f(lower) * f(upper) <= 0
In addition: Warning message:
In qt(sig.level/tside, nu, lower.tail = FALSE) : NaNs produced

Comment: I think you are not calculating the effect size (delta) correctly; your values are likely too large for the computations being run under the hood. See http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/116514/effect-size-for-a-one-sample-t-test